# Did anyone face anything bad by using IDEA EAP in productive environment?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have habit of not using EAP editions of IDEA but I wait for it become stable.

However, by looking at the log and user comments, I did not notice that anyone reported anything bad happened when using the EAP.

I am now thinking of start using EAP editions in my productive environment at my everyday job.

Before I do that, is there anyone who faced something bad by using EAP editions?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/ might be a better place for this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use mainly EAP for several years and the only bad thing I remember was when IJ commited more files into SVN than it should, that was in IJ 11 (but the bug was in a release also...).

Comment: I was just about to install when I saw comments in the blog section. A person is complaining about a big bug with SVN. It's very hard to trace such comments. I am now again reluctant to use EAP.

Comment: Too bad there is not a linked issue, anyways it works fine for me.